# Supporting URLs like /similar-to-:product in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, friendly-url

I have been trying to use routes.rb for creating a URL /similar-to-:product (where product is dynamic) for my website. The issue is that routes.rb readily supports URLs like /:product-similar but doesn't support the former because it requires :product to be preceded with a separator ('/' is a separator but '-' isn't). The list of separators is in ActionController::Routing::SEPARATORS.

I can't add '-' as a separator because :product can also contain a hyphen. What is the best way of supporting a URL like this?

One way that I have successfully tried is to not use routes.rb and put the URL parsing logic in the controller itself, but that isn't the cleanest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can add `-` as a separator, then use route globbing.

```
map.similar_product '/similar-to-*product', :controller => 'products', :action => 'similar'
```

then, in ProductsController#similar

```
@product = Product.find_by_slug params[:product].join('-')
```

Though refactoring does seem nicer, since with this approach you'll need to specially handle all slugs that can contain hyphens.

Comment: That isn't working. The url doesn't get matched to this route at all. I guess that is because even in this case *products should come after a separator.

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor your URLs so that they're simply "similar-to/product"

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is using a [routing filter](http://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter). See README for details.

With routing filter you can have a url `/similar-to-:product`, preprocess it to `/similar-to/:product` before it gets to routing recognition. You'll also want to post-process generated paths back from `/similar-to/:product` to `/similat-to-:product`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused, but could you maybe add "to-" as a seperator?

Comment: seems like rails supports only a single character as a separator